# scrollpane vertical scrollbar does not show scroll knob

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have created a JScrollPane and added a JTable to it. I want to be able to scroll to the bottom of the table using the vertical scrollbar. The scollpane is displayed with the table init however clicking on the top or bottom arrows does not progress the view to the top or bottom respectively. Also there is no scroll bar display in the vertical scroll track.

I've tried setting the viewport to different sizes, also using different constructors for creating the jscrollpane i.e. jscrollpane(table_3, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED); but none has worked.

```
public class test {
JFrame f;
int myMonth, myDay, myYear;
private JTable tblAppts;

private String[] colTimes = { "Time", "Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3" };
private Object[][] myTimes = { { "Time", "Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3" }, { 
"00:30", "", "", "" },
        { "01:00", "", "", "" }, { "01:30", "", "", "" }, { "02:00", "", 
 "", "" }, { "02:30", "", "", "" },
        { "03:00", "", "", "" }, { "03:30", "", "", "" }, { "04:00", "", 
 "", "" }, { "04:30", "", "", "" },
        { "05:00", "", "", "" }, { "05:30", "", "", "" }, { "06:00", "", 
"", "" }, { "06:30", "", "", "" },
        { "07:00", "", "", "" }, { "07:30", "", "", "" }, { "08:00", "", 
"", "" }, { "08:30", "", "", "" },
        { "09:00", "", "", "" }, { "09:30", "", "", "" }, { "10:00", "", 
"", "" }, { "10:30", "", "", "" },
        { "11:00", "", "", "" }, { "11:30", "", "", "" }, { "12:00", "", 
"", "" }, { "12:30", "", "", "" },
        { "13:00", "", "", "" }, { "13:30", "", "", "" }, { "14:00", "", 
"", "" }, { "14:30", "", "", "" },
        { "15:00", "", "", "" }, { "15:30", "", "", "" }, { "16:00", "", 
"", "" }, { "16:30", "", "", "" },
        { "17:00", "", "", "" }, { "17:30", "", "", "" }, { "18:00", "", 
"", "" }, { "18:30", "", "", "" },
        { "19:00", "", "", "" }, { "19:30", "", "", "" }, { "20:00", "", 
"", "" }, { "20:30", "", "", "" },
        { "21:00", "", "", "" }, { "21:30", "", "", "" }, { "22:00", "", 
"", "" }, { "22:30", "", "", "" },
        { "23:00", "", "", "" }, { "23:30", "", "", "" } };
private JTable tblTime;
private JTable table_1;
private JTable table_2;
private JTable table_3;

// set the table widths method
public static void setJTableColumnsWidth(JTable table, int 
tablePreferredWidth, double... percentages) {
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnModel().getColumnCount(); i++) {
        total += percentages[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnModel().getColumnCount(); i++) {
        TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
        column.setPreferredWidth((int) (tablePreferredWidth 
             (percentages[i] / total)));
    }
}

test() {

    f = new JFrame("WSDP");// creating instance of JFrame#
    // open the frame in a maximized state ie max vert and horizontal
    f.setSize(1000, 1000);
    f.setExtendedState(java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    // menus
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(0, 0, 982, 27);

    // create border
    Border blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
    panel.setBorder(blackline);
    f.getContentPane().add(panel);

    // icon buttons panel
    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setBounds(0, 26, 109, 593);
    panel_1.setBorder(blackline);
    f.getContentPane().add(panel_1);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    // scrollPane.setBounds(107, 78, 475, 875);
    scrollPane.setBounds(107, 78, 475, 500);
    // scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 110));
    scrollPane.setBorder(blackline);
    scrollPane.setViewportBorder(blackline);



    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy
                     (JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

    table_3 = new JTable(myTimes, colTimes);
    scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(table_3);
    table_3.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy
              (JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    table_3.setRowHeight(20);
    table_3.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 14));
    setJTableColumnsWidth(table_3, 480, 10, 30, 30, 30);
    f.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
    f.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    test t = new test();
}
```

}

Comment: edited with full program code

Comment: Problem #1 `f.getContentPane().setLayout(null);` - which is generally the root cause of your issue.  `JScrollPane` relies on a components `preferredSize` to make determinations about when to show (and how much) the scroll bars.  Since `JPanel` has a default `preferredSize` of `0x0`, it's not going to show anything

Comment: Okay, before this mess goes any further, you seriously need to go read through [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) as you have some fundamental misunderstandings of how the API works. I also recommend reading through [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) as it will solve many of the other problems you're about to face

Comment: `f.getContentPane().setLayout(null);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: Many thanks for your help, its finally working. I am a new java programmer and I appreciate the suggestions for reading up on use of tables and scroll panes.

Answer (score 1):

You seriously need to go read through [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) as you have some fundamental misunderstandings of how the API works.

You never set the `JScrollPane`'s viewport view...

I've stripped back your "example" to a complete and verifiable example which demonstrates the immediate resolutions of your issues...

[image: Example]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    private String[] colTimes = {"Time", "Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"};
    private Object[][] myTimes = {{"Time", "Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"}, {
        "00:30", "", "", ""},
    {"01:00", "", "", ""}, {"01:30", "", "", ""}, {"02:00", "",
        "", ""}, {"02:30", "", "", ""},
    {"03:00", "", "", ""}, {"03:30", "", "", ""}, {"04:00", "",
        "", ""}, {"04:30", "", "", ""},
    {"05:00", "", "", ""}, {"05:30", "", "", ""}, {"06:00", "",
        "", ""}, {"06:30", "", "", ""},
    {"07:00", "", "", ""}, {"07:30", "", "", ""}, {"08:00", "",
        "", ""}, {"08:30", "", "", ""},
    {"09:00", "", "", ""}, {"09:30", "", "", ""}, {"10:00", "",
        "", ""}, {"10:30", "", "", ""},
    {"11:00", "", "", ""}, {"11:30", "", "", ""}, {"12:00", "",
        "", ""}, {"12:30", "", "", ""},
    {"13:00", "", "", ""}, {"13:30", "", "", ""}, {"14:00", "",
        "", ""}, {"14:30", "", "", ""},
    {"15:00", "", "", ""}, {"15:30", "", "", ""}, {"16:00", "",
        "", ""}, {"16:30", "", "", ""},
    {"17:00", "", "", ""}, {"17:30", "", "", ""}, {"18:00", "",
        "", ""}, {"18:30", "", "", ""},
    {"19:00", "", "", ""}, {"19:30", "", "", ""}, {"20:00", "",
        "", ""}, {"20:30", "", "", ""},
    {"21:00", "", "", ""}, {"21:30", "", "", ""}, {"22:00", "",
        "", ""}, {"22:30", "", "", ""},
    {"23:00", "", "", ""}, {"23:30", "", "", ""}};
    private JTable table_3;

    public Test() {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("WSDP"); // creating instance of JFrame#
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

        table_3 = new JTable(myTimes, colTimes);
        table_3.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        // This is dangerous and is likely to come back and haunt you
        table_3.setRowHeight(20);
        table_3.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 14));

        // THIS is what's missing
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table_3);

        f.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I also recommend reading through [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) as it will solve many of the other problems you're about to face